# Is it allowed/adviseable to reuse a Collector?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have quite a lot spots in my code which do:

```
someStream.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

where `Collectors.toList()` creates a new collector on every use.

This leads me to the question if it is allowed and advisable to do something like:

```
private final static Collector<…> TO_LIST = Collectors.toList()
```

for every type I use and then make use of that single Collector like:

```
someStream.collect(TO_LIST)
```

when a collector is required.

As the collectors are stateless and just a collection of functions and characteristics, I should think it should work, but OTOH, `Collectors.toList()` creates a new `CollectorImpl<>` on every call.

What are the downsides of reusing a Collector?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think this is more of a *style* question, but lets give some thoughts:

- It seems to be **common** practice to **not** use such a CONST collector object. In that sense: doing so might surprise some readers, and surprising readers is rarely a good thing to do.
- Then: few code can be just "copied" around (and probably shouldn't to avoid code duplication); but still: pointing to a *distinct* collector object might make it a bit harder for you to re-factor or re-use your stream constructs.
- Beyond that: you stated it yourself; collector re-use **depends** on the a **stateless** implementation. So you make yourself dependent on any implementation being stateless. Probably not a problem; but maybe a *risk* to keep in mind!
- Probably more important: on the surface, your idea looks like a nice mean for *optimization*. But well; when you worry about the "performance effects" of using streams, then that one single object creation of the final collector will "not cut it"!

What I mean with that: if you are worried of "wasting" performance; you would rather look into each and any line of code that uses streams to determine whether that stream is working with "enough" objects to justify the usage of streams in the first place. Those streams come with **quite some** overhead!

Long story short: the java community has yet to find "standard best practices" for streams; thus my (personal) two cent at this time: prefer those patterns that "everybody" is using - avoid doing your own thing. Especially when it is "performance related".

Comment: The 3rd point, depending on a stateless, i.e. shareable implementation, is not an issue, as that’s what already happens in practice, e.g. when you pass a `Collector` as downstream collector to [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), which will reuse the collector for every group. It’s also implied by the individual contracts of the functions returned by the `Collector`.

Answer (score 33):

Since the `Collector` is basically a container for the four functions and characteristics flags, there is no problem reusing it, but also rarely any advantage, as the impact of such a lightweight object on the memory management is negligible, if not removed entirely by the optimizer anyway.

The main reason not to reuse `Collector`s, as seen with the builtin `Collectors`, is, that you can’t do it in a type safe way. When offering a collector for arbitrarily typed `List`s, you’ll need unchecked operations to always hand out the same `Collector` instance. If you store a `Collector` in a properly typed variable instead, to be used without unchecked operations, you can use it only for one type of `List`s, to stay with that example.

In the case of `Collections.emptyList()`, etc., the JRE developers went a different way, but the constants `EMPTY_LIST`, `EMPTY_MAP`, `EMPTY_SET` already existed before the introduction of Generics, and I’d say they are more versatile than the few cacheable `Collectors`, which are just four special cases out of the other more than thirty builtin collectors, which can’t be cached due to their function parameters. Since function parameters are often implemented via lambda expressions, which generate objects of unspecified identity/equality, a cache mapping them to collector instances would have an unpredictable efficiency, but very likely be far less efficient than the memory manager will deal with the temporary instances.

Comment: Indeed, I had these `EMPTY_*` things in mind where they give out the same object on every call.

Comment: That is the one great thing about this site: from time to time, there are these really interesting question; raising so many different and interesting answers!

Answer (score 13):

It is a good practice for a library to provide a **factory method** for obtaining useful objects. As the library *has provided* such a method: `Collectors.toList()`, it is again a good practice to *let the library decide* whether to create a new instance each time the object is requested or not, instead of tampering with the library, thus decreasing readability and risking the future problems when the implementation changes.

This to be added to the GhostCat's and Holger's answer as a supportive argument :)

Answer (score 6):

Just a tiny side-note, what @Holger is saying in his answer about the optimizer being smart and replacing that construct entirely is totally doable and it is called a `scalar replacement`. When an Object used inside a method is *de-constructed* and its fields are `stack allocated like normal local variables`. So that resulting `Collector` might not be treated at the JVM level as a Object per-se. That would happen at `JIT time`.

Answer (score 3):

The classic issue of using a single static object to stand in for one created on-the-fly is mutability. A quick scan of the Java 8 source highlights the `Set<Characteristics>` field as a possible problem.

Clearly it would be possible for some code somewhere to do something like:

```
private final static Collector<Object, ?, List<Object>> TO_LIST = Collectors.toList();


public void test() {
    // Any method could do this (no idea why but it should be possible).
    TO_LIST.characteristics().add(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
}
```

This *could* globally change the functionality of **every** use of `TO_LIST` which could create very obscure bugs.

So IMHO - don't!

Comment: Nice try, but this will throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. Generally, such JRE methods returning a `Collection` will return either, an immutable collection or a defensive copy.

Comment: To quote the [JavaDocs of Collector.characteristics()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#characteristics--): "This set should be immutable" (which is not a guarantee, but a very strong recommendation for implementors)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a case of premature optimization. Object creation is pretty cheap. On a normal laptop I would expect to be able to create between 10M-50M objects per second. With these numbers in mind the whole exercise becomes pointless.