# Why does java.util.stream.Collectors always create a new Collector?

Tags: java, java-stream

If I understand correctly, a `Collector` is an immutable tuple of functions.
So, why do the `Collectors` methods all create a new `Collector` for each request?
For example, as long as type erasure is happening, I would think that only one `toList()`
`Collector` is needed.

Comment: Good question. They probably thought it was worth the negligible cost to avoid unchecked casting and for consistency with the collectors that accept arguments. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864005/is-it-allowed-adviseable-to-reuse-a-collector

Comment: What makes you so sure it's more efficient to save one Collector for everyone to use?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not sure that reusing a Collector is more efficient, but it could be. I'm pretty sure that it is not less efficient, but feel free to explain how that could happen.

Comment: To reuse an object, you have to keep a reference to it, keeping its memory permanently allocated, regardless of whether you really need it at a later time. This is obviously less efficient than keeping the object only as long as you really need it. Accepting this disadvantage will only pay off if either 1) constructing the object is expensive, so skipping the construction saves time (does not apply to a collector) or 2) lots of instances are expected to potentially exist at the same time, so having one shared instance instead may have a net reduction of allocated memory (very unlikely here).